# Parse JSON files with 600k to 2mil lines in php and insert it in MySQL DB but it takes a lot of time

Tags: php, mysql, json

the JSON file looks sort of like this

`{"id":3924,"name":"xx","xxx":3.657}<br />   {"id":6124,"name":"xx","xxx":0.841}<br /> ...`

There are 600k lines, each containing a JSON file.

There is also a second file that contains 2mil of those lines and if my calculations are right, it would take me the whole day to parse it.

The code is below, I'm kinda new to this, is there a faster way to parse this than 400k per 6 hours?

```
`<?php

$dbhost = 'xx';
$dbuser = 'xx';
$dbpass = 'xx';
$DBname = 'xx';
$DB_List_Name = 'xx';
$JSONFileLocation=fopen(__DIR__.'\json\thefile.json','r');
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $DBname);

ini_set('max_execution_time', '40000'); //i think its pretty slow for 600000 rows


if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$file = $JSONFileLocation;
while (!feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);
    $obj = json_decode($line);

    $nameElem = addslashes($obj->name);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $DB_List_Name (
        id ,
        name,
        xxx
    )

    VALUES (
        '$obj->id',
        '$nameElem',
        '$obj->xxx'
    )";


    //that was for testing on low numbers
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        //printf("Table $DB_List_Name successfully updated.<br />");
        // echo '<br>';
    }
    else {
        //echo $obj->id.' - ';
        //printf("Error updating the table : %s<br />", $conn->error);
        //echo '<br>';
    }

}
echo 'End of the file: Everything is now in the database';
?>`
```

Comment: Provide this JSON file to MySQL as-is. LOAD DATA INFILE with input preprocessing will load this file into table by more effective way. 2kk lines with the data of shown format importing will take some minutes only.

Answer (score 0):

Experiment.

I generate a file of shown structure with 2kk lines, in which `id` is random integer, `name` is random string of 10-100 chars (avg length 15 chars) and `xxx` is decimal of 1-10 with 4 decimal digits.

I create a table:

```sql
create table test ( id int,
                    name varchar(255),
                    xxx decimal(6,4) );
```

Then I execute:

> ```sql
> mysql> load data infile "C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/json.txt"
>    -> into table test
>    -> lines terminated by '\r\n'
>    -> (@tmp)
>    -> set id = substring_index(substring_index(@tmp, ',', 1), ':', -1),
>    ->     name = trim(both '"' from substring_index(substring_index(@tmp, ',', 2), ':', -1)),
>    ->     xxx = trim( trailing '}' from (substring_index(@tmp, ':', -1)));
> Query OK, 2000000 rows affected (1 min 39.36 sec)
> Records: 2000000  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

Comment: @somePHPrando Do not forget to ensure that LOAD DATA is allowed and the file is placed in correct directory.

Comment: so, umm, the json line is a bit different actually
{"aaa":false,"id":3924,"name":"xxxxx","bbb":3.657,"ccc":false}

i tried adapting your code to what I need and got this:
"set id = trim(both '"' from substring_index(substring_index(@tmp, ',', 2), ':', -1)),
name = trim(both '"' from substring_index(substring_index(@tmp, ',', 3), ':', -1)),
bbb = trim(both '"' from substring_index(substring_index(@tmp, ',', 4), ':', -1));"

but what I got in result was next:
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.046 sec); Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0;

am I doing something wrong?

Comment: that one record is correct, but it is the only one that has been parsed

Comment: @somePHPrando Parsing expression is correct: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9f1e5f6d48fab3e6bc48f92e1de877d1 Maybe your file is unix text? if so then adjust `lines terminated by` parameter. PS. Numbers are not wrapped with `"`, so their trimming is excess.

Comment: alright, changing to '\n' seems to work, now, instead of 6 hours it takes a few minutes, holy shit, thank you very much for this. ps. yeah, I just copied the same lines for numbers ;D